# Design a restful url to validate the object

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, restful-url

Is it possible to populate java object in spring MVC from restful URL.

To clarify, can I make a url like 
localhost:8080/user/email/a@a.com/password/aaa
which will populate email and password field of User object and return me user?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/email/{email}/password/{password}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Users> createNewUserRegistration(@Valid User user) {

}
```

Comment: probably don't but you can always do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ResponseEntity<Users> createNewUserRegistration(@PathVariable("email")String email,@PathVariable("password")String password) {
User user = new User(email,password);
//do validation etc
return user;
}
```

Comment: There are so many manual way to do the validation, I was asking about Spring MVC validation using @valid. There are several way like post json via rest api, which I was avoiding.

Comment: for me it is a not good practice to use email as path param. You can use `@Valid` everywhere in your methods. You can use with `@RequestBody` ,`@RequestParam` etc

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally it worked for me. You need to add it in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>

@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Users> createNewUserRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {

}
```

and pass the json in the request body

```
{
    "emailAddress":"email",
    "password":"password"
}
```